# Oracle-Decidability of Algebraic Independence

Tags: oracles, decidability, undecidability

Consider numbers $x_1,...,x_n\in \mathbb{R}$ given by TMs $M_1,...,M_n$ such that $M_i$ approximates $x_i$ to an arbitrary precision (by allowing it to run longer and longer).

I am interested in the following problem:

> Decide whether $x_1,...,x_n$ are algebraically independent.

Clearly this is undecidable, since even deciding whether $x_i=0$ is undecidable. However, if we are given an oracle to the problem of deciding whether $x_i=0$, then the above problem becomes *recognizable*: enumerate all polynomials with integer coefficients (e.g. in minlex order), and for each polynomial $p$ compute a TM $M_p$ that approximates $p(x_1,...,x_n)$ arbitrarily. Then, use the oracle to check if this number is $0$.

So the question is:

> Is the problem also decidable under a zero-test oracle? i.e. is it co-recognizable?

Remarks:

1. This question relates (but is not directly connected/reducible to) my question [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/32451/is-algebraic-dependency-decidable).
2. I see that a lot of questions regarding real-numbers encounter issues with encoding. I think the encoding here is well defined (comment if I'm wrong, and I'll revise). Note that not all numbers are of course representable in this model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is **no**; interestingly, the problem is harder to *state* satisfactorily in my opinion than it is to resolve! Roughly speaking, the subtlety which complicates the posing of the problem is that the "context of computation" is **more complicated than** the distinctions we want to make. Below I'll refer frequently to the [arithmetical hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy), and focus on the following three sets of natural numbers in particular:

- The set $R$ of indices of Turing machines which "code" a real number.
- The set $Z$ of indices of Turing machines which "code" the real number $0$. (This is what we want to use as an oracle; note that $Z\subset R$.)
- The set $T$ of indices of Turing machines which "code" a *transcendental* number (for simplicity I'm looking at the "$n=1$ slice" of the actual set you're interested in).

---

Here's the above-mentioned subtlety: each of these three sets, including the "background context" set $R$, is $\Pi^0_2$-complete. In particular, all three sets are Turing- *(indeed, many-one-)*${}$equivalent, and live at a significantly higher level of complexity than the intuitive ("zero-testing") gap between $R$ and $Z$, namely the halting problem. This means that "$T$ is computable relative to $Z$" is technically true but feels wrong somehow.

So we have a methodological question to address:

### How can the question in the OP be made precise while blocking this sort of trivial response?

*(Incidentally a similar issue, albeit "higher up," occurs in [the context of computing general antiderivatives](https://www.jstor.org/stable/421157) - look for the phrase "hyperarithmetic **in the codes**." In this setting "the codes" is a $\Pi^1_1$-complete set, while hyperarithmeticity is $\Delta^1_1$.)*

One natural approach is to shift from the usual picture of oracles as *total* objects to *partial* oracles. This would let us distinguish for example between the characteristic function of $Z$, which is a very powerful object, and the *partial* function $$Z_R:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}:x\mapsto\begin{cases}
1 & \mbox{ if } x\in Z,\\
0 & \mbox{ if } x\in R\setminus Z,\\
\uparrow & \mbox{ if }x\not\in R.\\
\end{cases}$$ which should be rather weaker. A similar distinction would exist between "total $T$" and $T_R$, and we would be interested in gauging the complexity of $T_R$ relative to $Z_R$.

Unfortunately it takes some care to get computation relative to partial objects to work properly. While in my opinion this effort is very much worthwhile, in this case I'll take a simpler approach - basically, throw Venn diagrams on everything and hope for the best!

---

We can rephrase the OP's motivating observation as saying that while both $R$ and $Z$ are $\Pi^0_2$-complete, $Z$ "sits inside" $R$ in a noticeably $\Pi^0_1$-complete way: there is a $\Pi^0_1$-complete set $\hat{Z}$ such that $Z=R\cap\hat{Z}$, and this is optimal in the sense that there is no $\Sigma^0_1$ (let alone computable) set $A$ such that $Z=R\cap A$. We can ask whether $T$ is similarly "nontrivially simple" in terms of how it fits inside $R$.

At this point a bit of terminology is in order. Sadly I don't think there is a standard terminology for this sort of thing, but the following matches what I've heard in some informal conversations:

> For a complexity class $\Gamma$ *(especially a class in the arithmetical hierarchy)* and a set $X$, say that a set $Y$ **is $\Gamma$ on $X$**, or $Y\in\Gamma_{\cap X}$, iff there is some $A\in\Gamma$ with $Y=X\cap A$.

My point, then, is that the question in the OP can be faithfully precisiated as:

> For which arithmetical classes $\Gamma$ is $T\in\Gamma_{\cap R}$?

*(Incidentally, note that in general - letting $\check{\Gamma}$ be the set of sets whose complements are in $\Gamma$  we have $\Gamma_{\cap X}\cap\check{\Gamma}_{\cap X}\supsetneq(\Gamma\cap\check{\Gamma})_{\cap X}$.)*

For example, the slightly-informal observation in the OP that $T$ becomes co-enumerable once we have an oracle for $Z$ corresponds to the fact that $T\in\Pi^0_{2\cap R}$ (since "co-enumerable in $\Pi^0_1$" = $\Pi^0_2$), and optimality of this bound would correspond to $T\color{red}{\not\in}\Sigma^0_{2\cap R}$. That this holds is a consequence of the following:

> Not only is $T$ $\Pi^0_2$-complete in the usual sense, it is "$\Pi^0_2$-complete within $R$:" for every $A\in\Pi^0_2$ there is a total computable $f$ which is an $m$-reduction of $A$ to $T$ **and** has range $\subseteq R$.

This isn't hard to prove; basically, given a $\Pi^0_2$ property $\varphi$ and an input $n$, build a number whose binary expansion consists of:

- a block of $0$s which keeps going until (if ever) we see that $0$ is not a witness to $\varphi(n)$, then the string $01^{2^0}0$,
- then a block of $0$s which keeps going until (if ever) we see that $1$ is not a witness to $\varphi(n)$, then the string $01^{2^1}0$,
- then a block of $0$s which keeps going until (if ever) we see that $2$ is not a witness to $\varphi(n)$, then the string $01^{2^2}0$,
- and so on.

The resulting number is a dyadic rational iff $\varphi(n)$ holds, and is otherwise transcendental [for Liouville-flavored reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number) (possibly after fixing any silly arithmetic errors I've made in the above :P).

Comment: Nice answer! Thanks. By now I don't even have a vague memory of why I was interested in this question, but still - great to have an answer! :)

Comment: What do you mean by “The resulting number is a dyadic rational iff φ(n)
 holds”?  what is $\phi (x)$? It's definition?

Comment: @XL_At_Here_There $\varphi$ is an arbitrary $\Pi^0_2$ property; see the sentence beginning "this isn't hard to prove." (And look in Soare's book if you're not familiar with $\Pi^0_2$ completeness proofs.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber, thanks.

Comment: @NoahSchweber,  by what theorem, it can be deduced that "The resulting number is a dyadic rational iff $\varphi(n)$
 holds"?