# By Gödel numbering, is the set of computable(partially) transcendental numbers an immune set, productive set?

Tags: computability

Every Turing Machine computing(output) real number is encoded as a natural number, namely, admissible numbering. Then what is the set of computable (partially) transcendental numbers? Is it an immune set? A productive set?

Comment: I think this is largely subsumed by https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/33406/oracle-decidability-of-algebraic-independence.

Comment: @NoahSchweberN， I am not sure

Comment: @XL_At_Here_There: The answer linked by Noah observes right from the start that the set you're asking about is $\Pi^0_2$-complete. That's a direct answer to your question. (Noah goes on, though, because the answer can be improved if we re-interpret the question.)

Comment: @AndrejBauer, thanks,   I will read the answer carefully.  And maybe Mr. Schweber is unwilling to go on because of some reason. Could you give an answer  if if we re-interpret the question?

Comment: I am confused. You're asking me to copy Noah Schweber's answer from the other question over here.

Comment: @AndrejBauer, if the question is re-interpreted, what answer would you give?

Comment: This one: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/33406/oracle-decidability-of-algebraic-independence

Comment: @AndrejBauer, thank you, I have read the answer carefully, and possibly have understood the post. you say let Mr.Schweber go on improving the answer, so I say possibly he is not willing to, and would you....... anyway, thank you for your comments

Comment: @XL_At_Here_There: I only now saw you're a teacher who is not a mathematician in your profile. I apologize for being so curt, I'll take your non-mathematicianess into account henceforth.

Comment: @AndrejBauer, about twenty years ago, some theoritical thinking about what I am doing  had lead me to a new definition of Kolmogorov Complexity,  Since then, having learnt part of logic and it's branch, I have more questions about what I am doing in the view of math. So,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152091/discussion-between-xl-at-here-there-and-andrej-bauer).